# URL rewrite disable opening files

Tags: php, image, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I hope I can clear my question. I have a Rewrite rule. It works properly but if I type dot and file extension it looks for directory. I want to remove that. Basically I want to edit the uploaded images on my website

If you don't understand my question I can explain it better with examples.

I have folders "/uploads/images/". Then I have image inside (ex. test.jpg). My controller works by opening class file with the 1st parameter and looking for function with the name of the 2nd parameter. So in case I try to open

```
www.example.com/uploads/images
```

it will try to open class.uploads.php and run function called images. I also have 3rd parameter - $_GET['s'] and my class looks like this:

```
class uploads{
    public function images(){
        $img = Database::Map("s/string");
        $img = $img['s'];
        die($img);
    }
}
```

I want when user enters www.example.com/uploads/images/test.jpg my function to be executed and not open the file. Also I want to only make this rule for the uploads folder.

This is my .htaccess rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?/?([^/\.]+)?/?([^/\.]+)?/?([^/\.]+)?/?$ index.php?act=$1&p=$2&s=$3&ss=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

And this is my front controller:

```
...
$_GET["act"] = strtolower($_GET["act"]);
$Page = new $_GET["act"];
if($_GET['p'] == NULL && $_GET['act'] != NULL)$_GET['p'] = "index";
if(method_exists($Page,$_GET["p"]) == false)$Core->GoPage("/NotFound/");
if(method_exists($Page,"PreRun") == true)$Page->PreRun();
if(isset($_GET["s"]) == false)$Page->{$_GET["p"]}();
if(isset($_GET["s"]) == true)$Page->{$_GET["p"]}($_GET["s"]);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your uploads folder, create an `.htaccess` file with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /class.uploads.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Create a file named `class.uploads.php` at your root `/` and then have it call your function `images()`.

Then you can retrieve the filename or directory that was requested in PHP via:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

If you need this rule to act on only `.jpg` then we can change the rewrite rule.  Otherwise this will support `.png`, `.gif`, and even directories like `/uploads/user1234/images/`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast reply. This would work but I already have a RewriteRule. I added more details to my question. Can you help me integrate it with my current rule ?

Comment: That is an interesting rewrite you currently have and technically a new question.  Let me think.  If you create a new question while I look, I'll just look at that one.  Wait, you need changes to the PHP too?  Yeah I'm not sure how to integrate into your current rewrite rule, mind accepting and creating a new question because of the edits?

Comment: I don't mind but I think creating a new question, but as long as I know it's against Stack Overflow rules. I was banned once and I don't want to get banned again. Also I don't want any changes in the PHP, I've just posted it to explain how my controller works as clear as possible

Comment: Well it's not against StackOverflow rules, it's just frowned upon.  It's called a "chameleon question":  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275138/how-to-deal-with-op-asking-another-questions-after-answering-original-question/275140#275140  While I spent the time to answer the original question, I am not equipped enough to answer the new question about modifying your current rewrite rule (especially without knowing more about it and the intentions).

Comment: I'm curious, were you able to find an answer to how to modify your rewrite rule?